# first log in - how to enter as a user account and not as guest

Tags: login

I have just turned on my Dell computer with Ubuntu 14.04 for the first time. It only gives me access to a Guest Session log in, in which i can not change
any settings (like adding account). How I can log in as a user account for the first time?

thanks, Mario.

Comment: didn't you create a user account when you installed the OS?

Comment: I did not install the OS. I bought the notebook with the OS installed

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work, but try `sudo gnome-terminal` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> without typing a password.

If it does work, type `adduser [your name]` and fill in the information.  Log out after that and log into your new user account.

This problem was probably caused by skipping a step of the setup, or possibly from a modified iso that had that part removed, if you didn't get the iso from a reliable source.

Answer (score 0):

Search for 'user' in the search bar.

[image: im1]

Now Select User Accounts.

[image]

Now click on the little '+' sign.

[image]

Now select the account as an Administrator and put your name and user name. (User name should not contain spaces.) Now click on add.

[image]

Now click on 'Account disabled'.

[image]

Now enter a password for your os. (Remember the password always).

[image]

Now you are done. You can restart now.